# '?' Delimiter in getline fixes error but why?

Tags: c++

I have a program that gets input from a text file line by line, performs some modifications and then outputs the line to another file.  I encountered an error where some (not all) whitespace chars were not being printed to the output file.  What fixed the problem was this:

`getline(inFile,fileBuff);` --> `getline(inFile,fileBuff,'?');`

Why does adding the question mark as a delimiter fix the problem?

EDIT: Here is some of the input file:

VA PELCGBTENCUL N PNRFNE PVCURE NYFB XABJA NF PNRFNEF
PVCURE GUR FUVSG PVCURE PNRFNEF PBQR BE PNRFNE FUVSG VF BAR
BS GUR FVZCYRFG NAQ ZBFG JVQRYL XABJA RAPELCGVBA GRPUAVDHRF

(the space between NYFB and XABJA was being skipped)

Here is the getline loop:

```
while(!inFile.eof()){
    getline(inFile,fileBuff,'?');
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<fileBuff.length(); i++){
        if(fileBuff.at(i)>=65 && fileBuff.at(i)<=90){
            cipherInt=(int)(fileBuff.at(i)-64);
            plainInt=(cipherInt-13)%26;
            if(plainInt<0)
                plainInt+=26;
            numFile << "(" << cipherInt << ")";
            outFile << (char)(plainInt+64);
        }else{
            numFile << " ";
            outFile << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the default delimiter is the newline character `'\n'`. That is what specifies a line.

Comment: But you really should show us the code you have so we can *really* see why it works as opposed to `'\n'`.

Comment: also show some example lines from your input file

Comment: Have you tried to delete the whitespace and press space between NYFB and XABJA just to make sure it is actually a white space? Typical encoding format errors when reading/writing results in a question mark so I think you should just try that (long shot).

Comment: @Phataas What's interesting is gdb tells me that space is 32 ascii.  Also, the code should print a space if the char is anything other than A-Z; even with an encoding format error, it should default to printing a space.